# TypeScript .map: Adding new property to array of objects. Property does not exist on type

Tags: typescript

```
type Cat = { name: string; fur: "brown" | "white" };

const addOrigin = (animals: Cat[], origin: "Italy" | "France") =>
    animals.map((animal) => (animal.origin = origin)); // animal.origin throws error (see below)
```

throws

`Property 'origin' does not exist on type 'Cat'.ts(2339)`

Is there a way to leave the `Cat` type as it is and to implement something like `OriginAddedCat` into `addOrigin` function?

Comment: That's not a mapping. To use `Array.map` the expectation is that the selector function has no side effects. This is not the case here, because your code (if it worked) would mutate values that already exist. If you want to perform side-effects over your existing array, you're better off using `Array.forEach`, but be warned that mutation of existing data can make code much harder to understand. Use `Array.map`, but don't mutate what passes thru the mapping func... construct an array of new objects (as per [@JamesElderfield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70214068/14357))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Array.map` the return value of the passed function is used to construct the elements of the new array. In your case this would be,

```
type Cat = { name: string; fur: "brown" | "white" };

const addOrigin = (animals: Cat[], origin: "Italy" | "France") =>
    animals.map((animal) => ({ ...animal, origin }));
```

The return type of `addOrigin` will now include the `origin` property.

You could let type inference do the rest, but if you want to define the `OriginAddedCat` then you could either do,

```
interface Cat {
    name: string;
    fur: "brown" | "white";
}

interface OriginAddedCat extends Cat {
   origin: "Italy" | "France";
}
```

or

```
type OriginAddedCat = Cat & { origin: "Italy" | "France" };
```

or

```
type OriginAddedCat = ReturnType<typeof addOrigin>[number];
```

Comment: yeah, thank you. i feel pretty dumb after asking this question, it was a long working day that day :D